# TypeORM Entity Listener @BeforeRemove - cannot access to Entity data - undefined

Tags: nestjs, entity, listener, typeorm

I am trying to reach the data of the being deleted Entity with `@BeforeRemove` listener in TypeORM, but it is impossible. I am getting always `undefined`.

It makes no sense to me, because `@BeforeRemove`, in my understanding, should be triggered before removing the data and there should be a possibility to reach them in the function underneath the decorator. There is also `@AfterRemove` and it seems to work in the same way.

Any ideas or tips why this is happening? I am using NestJS.

There is my listener code in Entity:

```
@BeforeRemove()
decrementLikes() {
    console.log(this.item) // -> this logs undefined always
    this.itemsRepository.createQueryBuilder()
    .update(Item)
    .set({ likes: () => 'likes - 1' })
    .where('id = :id', { id: this.item })
    .execute();
}
```

Here is the service code which triggers the listener:

```
async deleteFavorite(favorite: UserFavoriteDto): Promise<void> {
    const fav = await this.usersFavoritesRepository.find(favorite);
    await this.usersFavoritesRepository.remove(fav);
}
```

Comment: Hi could you find out how to do it?